# Help on a triphasic test exercise

Tags: power, three-phase

[image: Diagram]

On the above picture, **VAB** is **380 V**, balanced loads.

The right answer says power on Wattmeter A is **0** and power on wattmeter C is **7240 W**.

This question came from a previous admission test from a power company

I need help understanding why the zero.

Also, why do I have to ignore the phase of the source ?

**The following was edited. See edit history if necessary**

I tried:

`VAB²/(2*Z)`

`380<0² / 2*10<60`

Which results in 7220 (not 7240, but I believe it's an approach error).

Also, kindly answer another question I made, which I believe is related:

[Relation between phase angle and current direction](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/469329/relation-between-phase-angle-and-current-direction?noredirect=1#comment1186075_469329)

The answers there don't seem, to my eyes, related to the question. And they came before I enhanced the question.

Comment: Unless I'm really missing something, the power reading on W_A and W_C must be equal as it's a balanced supply and load. Are the W things wattmeters?

Comment: Correct: wattmeters, balanced loads. I suppose that two currents are entering the load and another one is leaving. That's why I linked the other thread I made. This question came from a power company admission test

Comment: The "right answer" looks wrong. Apart from that, the power calculation must be done on the phase-neutral voltage if you are using Z as the load because the load on each phase is between phase and neutral so your `VAB²/Z + VBC²/Z + VCA²/Z` line doesn't look right but your next one does.

Comment: Corrected the attempted calculations (left intact the part you quoted so your comment makes sense). The "right answer" can be trusted. This came from a test applied STATEWIDE three years ago. The company DOES nullify questions when their alternatives/answers are messed.

Comment: What is STATEWIDE? You're on an international site and you have no location in your user profile. Can you post an image of the actual question? There's got to be something else.

Comment: I see your edit now. You can't do `VAB²/2*Z` because you're omitting the effect of \$I_C\$ on the Z on line B. Use $$ \frac {\sqrt 3 V_{AB}^2}{Z} $$ (I think!).

Comment: There's a reason why I didn't post the actual question. Here it is: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AilzHUVAr7w5hXku_zICa-KkRaBD  Statewide means there are candidates among a population of a million and a half. Maybe we should cleanup this comment area. Getting long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This answer was edited. If needed, see history**

It is known that the sum of the two wattmeters is the total power of the load, but it doesn't mean that both of them will present the same value, since the **sources** are **out of phase**. As noted by Transistor, the wattmeters read the lines in sequence.

Found a document with an exercise. Refer to example 20.1 or 20.3

https://nptel.ac.in/content/storage2/courses/108105053/pdf/L-20(NKD)(ET)%20((EE)NPTEL).pdf

Also, from the same document:

```
PF=1 → W1=W2
PF=0.5 (cos60) → W1=Total power
0.5<PF<1 → W1>W2
```

---

**For the proposed problem:**

Total power (all three loads):

```
P=|VL|²/R*cos(<Z)
OR
P=3*|Vp|*|Ip|*cos(<Z)
```

Line power:

```
W1=|VL|*|IL|*cos(<V+(|<I|))
W2=|VL|*|IL|*cos(<V-(|<I|))

With <V being the angle between the Line voltage and the Reference (usually, the angle is 30°) , and |<I| being the positive angle between the Line current and the Reference
```

In my case:

```
W1= 380*220/10*cos(30+60)= 0
W2= 380*220/10*cos(30-60)= 7240
```

I wish I could find a shorter formula that takes the angles into account (0, -120, 120) instead

This answer is free to be improved

Comment: I haven't checked your calculations but I have realised that while the supply and load are balanced the metering isn't. If \$ W_A \$ and \$ W_B \$ were referenced to the next phase in the sequence (rather than both referenced to B) then they would read the same. Or if Z is purely resistive both would read the same. +1 for the question and the answer. I've deleted my answer.

Comment: Along with the deleted answer, my thank you went away. But that one deserved to stay. So, thank you again for the hours of support

Comment: No problem. Don't forget you can accept your own answer to indicate the problem is solved.